# How to call function only when async call from service is completed?

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, service

In my controller I have a createListing() function that is called when a form is submitted.  createListing() then calls on the saveListing() function from within the newListingService service, which makes an $http post request to the database.  I then need to update the listings shown on the page to include the newly created listing using the updateListings() function in the controller.  The problem that I am having is that the updateListings() function is being called BEFORE the saveListing() call in createListing().  How can I make sure that updateListings() will only be called AFTER the post request is completed?

Controller:

```
 ...

  $scope.listings = {};

  $scope.updateListings = function(){
    $http.get('/listings')
       .then(function(res){
          $scope.listings = res.data;
        });
      };

   $scope.createListing = function(listingData){
     newListingService.saveListing(listingData);
     $scope.updateListings();
   };
```

newListingService:

```
function newListingService($http){
  this.saveListing = function(listingData){
    $http({
      method  : 'POST',
      url     : '/listings',
      data    : listingData
    })
    .success(function(data) {
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@depiction is right.You should use `promises`.

But, `$http` returns promise itself. Thus,you don't have to use `$q` or anything else. Just return the request and it will returns its `promise`:

```
this.saveListing = function(listingData){
   return $http({
            method  : 'POST',
            url     : '/listings',
            data    : listingData
          });
}
```

and in your controller:

```
newListingService.saveListing(listingData)
    .then(function(response){
        $scope.updateListings();
    }, function(err){
       // handle error here
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use promises.

```
function newListingService($http){
    this.saveListing = function(listingData){

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http({
      method  : 'POST',
      url     : '/listings',
      data    : listingData
    })
    .then(
        function success(data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        },
        function error(response) {
            deferred.resolve(false);
        }
    );

    return deferred.promise;

  }
}
```